# Get substring from string in C# using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like:

```
Brief Exercise 1-1 Types of Businesses Brief Exercise 1-2 Forms of Organization Brief Exercise 1-3 Business Activities.
```

I want to break above string using regular expression so that it can be like:

```
Types of Businesses
Forms of Organization
Business Activities.
```

Please don't say that I can break it using 1-1, 1-2 and 1-3 because it will bring the word "Brief Exercise" in between the sentences. Later on I can have Exercise 1-1 or Problem 1-1 also. So I want some general Regular expression.

Any efficient regular expression for this scenario ?

Comment: Without knowing the rules by which you want to "break" the string, we can't suggest a solution, regex or otherwise.

Comment: According to above scenario i want to break using "Brief Exercise 1-(n)" where n is 1,2 3, and so on.

Comment: In that case, what have you tried? Is it _always_  a `1-(n)`? Or can it be a `(n)-(m)`? In either case, what range can `n` and `m` have?

Comment: n = [0-9] any number. It is not fixed. It can go up till 40 or 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression will match on "Brief Exercise 1-" followed by a digit and an optional second digit:

```
@"Brief Exercise 1-\d\d?"
```

---

Update:

Since you might have "Problem" as well, an alternation between `Exercise` and `Problem` is also needed (using non capturing parenthesis):

```
@"Brief (?:Exercise|Problem) 1-\d\d?"
```

Comment: I think it is the easiest and efficient approach.

Comment: You need to escape the \d, either as \\d or put an @ infront of the string, see my answer. Also you need to match the trailing space!

Comment: I just need one clarification. If I have variable like marker = "Brief Exercise 1" then how can I put it in Regular expression ?

Comment: @fawad - It needs to be inserted into the string directly. using `string.Format` with format specifiers can do the trick.

Comment: I'm not good in regular expression. Can you please write the syntax ?

Comment: @fawad - If you have such a literal, you simply need to insert it into the string. I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Like I don't want to hard code the regular express in the code. I want the string (Brief exercises, problem, exercises) to be picked from textbox. Are you getting what I want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6417/discussion-between-fawad-and-oded)

Comment: @fawad - Do you know how to use `string.Format`? You can insert a value into a string with it.

Comment: @fawad - The documentation on MSDN is good. Start by reading it.

Answer (score 3):

```
var regex=new Regex(@"Brief (?:Exercise|Problem) \d+-\d+\s");
var result=string.Join("\n",regex.Split(x).Where(a=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)));
```

The regex will match "Brief " followed by either "Exercise" or "Problem" (the ?: makes the group non capturing), followed by a space, then 1 or more digits then a "-", then one or more digits then a space.

The second statement uses the split function to split the string into an array and then regex to skip all the empty entries (otherwise the split would include the empty string at the begining, you could use `Skip(1)` instead of `Where(a=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))`, and then finally uses string.Join to combine the array back into string with \n as the seperator.

You could use regex.Replace to convert directly to \n but you will end up with a \n at the begining that you would have to strip.

--EDIT---

if the fist number is always 1 and the second number is 1-50ish you could use the following regex to support 0-59

```
var regex=new Regex(@"Brief (?:Exercise|Problem) 1-\[1-5]?\d\s");
```

Comment: Why `Problem`? Where do you see that?

Comment: @Oded From the question "Later on I can have Exercise 1-1 or Problem 1-1 also"

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it the easy way? I mean, if the regular part is "Brief Exercise #-#" Replace it by some split character and then split the resulting string to obtain what you want.

If you do it otherwise you will always have to take care of special cases.

```
string pattern = "Brief Exercise \d+-\d+";
Regex reg = new Regex(patter);
string out = regex.replace(yourstring, "|");
string results[] = out.split("|");
```

Comment: Regex has a split function so you can combine your last two statements into one split function

Comment: Also you will need to escape the \d hence... either \\d or put an @ infront of the string definition.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see your answer at the time. Learned something new ;)